# How to retrieve an (image) file from the database and place that into a form when updating a record?

Tags: php, forms, filenames

I got an issue where I cant display the filename on a form while updating a record. I'll try to explain it verbally since I'm unable to display any pictures.

For normal input fields, I am able to retrieve the specific field that I want form my database. For example:

```
<label for="name">Product Name:</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="30" size="25" value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" name="product_name" />
```

But when it comes down to the image-input section, I cannot retrieve the name of the file that I've uploaded. I did the method as show below, but it does not display the filename but the phrase 'No file selected' when I run my codes

```
<label for="image">Product Image    </label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $product_image;?>" accept="image/*" />
```

I have added the [enctype='multipart/form-data'] part at my  tag but it still doesn't work.

What PHP solution is there to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing the images in database?

Comment: The usual [move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)]

Comment: So, what is the content of your product_image field? A path to where the image is stored?

Comment: I don't understand the 1st part of your question.. As for the 2nd part, the path is just images/bugatti_veyron.jpg

Comment: Well change your input for: `<img src='<?php echo $product_image;?>' />`

Comment: I don't want to display the image itself but rather just the filename as I want to change the image if I were to do an update of that specific record.

Answer (score 2):

No You can't set values in `file` control. You can show as

```
 Existing image:  <img src='<?php echo $file_name;?>' alt='old_image'/>

 Upload new image: <input type='file' name='image' id='image'/>
```

If you are storing image in db, then you have to pass the record id to a `PHP` to get the image on the fly. there are lot of tutorial available for handling image with db.

this the way you can do.

In your update action, just check if `$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]` is empty or not. If it's empty, then no change in image field. If it's not empty, the you have to replace the old image with new image and update the record in db.

Comment: Then how do I show the filename that I currently have next to the 'Browse' button that allows me to select a new image from my computer?

Comment: when do you want to select? After form submit? or from DB?

Comment: From the database that is. If I want to display the filename alone outside of the form. Then I am able to do it, but I'm unable to do so in the form.

Comment: How you are storing image? Only filename or as `blob` content?

Comment: I'm storing my images on a filename basis.. Being a junior to programming, I did not use blob when storing my images

Comment: Hmmm.. Yes I did.. Sorry if I've replied late.. I guessed that I was too brazen with my ideas.. :X

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible the only way I think you can do this is echo the image from the database into a text file where user can view it if there is need for change then the user will enter a new one on the form